# What is the significance of google_tag_params - why do I code twice?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working on Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics and noticed that the previous developer has calls like this

```
var google_tag_params = {
    "visitorLoginState":"logged-out",
    "visitorType":"visitor-logged-out",
    "pageTitle":"BECOME, The Sports, Fashion &amp; Fitness Blog from SSS",
    "pagePostType":"frontpage",
    "browserName":"Firefox",
    "browserVersion":"43.0",
    "browserEngineName":"Gecko",
    "browserEngineVersion":"43.0"
};
dataLayer.push({
    "visitorLoginState":"logged-out",
    "visitorType":"visitor-logged-out",
    "pageTitle":"",
    "pagePostType":"frontpage",
    "browserName":"Firefox",
    "browserVersion":"43.0",
    "browserEngineName":"Gecko",
    "browserEngineVersion":"43.0"
    "google_tag_params":window.google_tag_params
});
```

In the `dataLayer` object he uses `google_tag_params` and pushes the data from the previous object inside here. But he is repeating all the previous same variables dynamically such as `visitorLoginState` and `pageTitle` etc.. do I need to do the same and repeat it?

Google Tag Manager docs is not clear on this and just states it is a supported tag with no clear examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the syntax per se - populating an object before you push it to the dataLayer is arguably more readable than having a nested structure.

However the data in google_tag_params seems off, because traditionally google_tag_params is the name you use for parameters for [Adwords remarketing tags](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3103357?hl=en). While this is a convention and not a technical necessity I would rather expect values for pagetype, product ids and and total value in gtm_tag_params.

It is possible that yours is some unusual use case, but it's more likely that the previous developer did something wrong. You'd have to check how the variable is used in your tag management container.